# How to use workflow to send a link to a specific page in an email

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, workflow

I am building an approval workflow which will send an email to a named individual, directing them to a specific project to review the work done there.

I am having trouble embedding a link to the site homepage in the email. It cannot be hard-coded as the site to be approved will change with each iteration of the workflow so it needs to be a lookup.

The approval workflow runs against a list containing data about the project. When the workflow is invoked by a change to the list item it needs to embed a link to the homepage of the site into an email.

Comment: You can add one multiple lines of text(enhanced rich field) to store the link of subsite. And you can directly use this field in your email body in workflow.

Comment: Can you give examples? Can you explain logic how you understand what URL to choose as human and we can suggest implementation ways programmatically?

Comment: are you using SharePoint Workflow 2010 or 2013 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create variable: 'ProjectName' and fill it with a CurrentItem:Property a project Name (if its as URL) you you should have something in the list item as unique identifier.

You can use link only to the Web without the Page.aspx, like : https://SP.company.com/projects/0010 because HomePage will be loaded automatically.

Use In Link this Variable to complete URL:
[image]

[image]

It will send email with Link to project on its running.

*I Used SharePoint Workflow 2010.*